# Question on customizing Django auth templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I'm using Django 3 and Python 3.7.

I've been fuddling through some of the tempalates, but I can't seem to get "success" templates to be found, for instance "password_change_done" and "password_reset_done".  Both give similar Error messages.

> NoReverseMatch at /users/password_change/
>
> Reverse for 'password_change_done' not found. 'password_change_done' is not a
> valid view function or pattern name.

I have this in my project urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [
      path( "users/", include( "users.urls" ) )
    , path( "admin/", admin.site.urls )
    , path( "", include( "main.urls" ) )  #  Played with this up top, and here on the bottom.
]
```

And in users\urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
      #  Include default auth urls.
      path( "", include( "django.contrib.auth.urls" ) )
      ...
]
```

I even tried adding a TEMPLATES.DIRS value to point to user/templates.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [ os.path.join( BASE_DIR, "users/templates" ) ],  #  With and Without this.
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        ...
        },
    },
]
```

I feel like `path( "", include( "django.contrib.auth.urls" ) )` should contain the correct reference, but do I need to list each one individually?  How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Reference a specific view for your custom URL as following.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
   path('change-password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
]
```

Check out the details from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views).

Comment: Hi, I don't think this answers my question.  I don't have a custom view, I'm including the auth urls and its not finding the reverse for "password_change_done".  I detailed this above, and here is the default entry from github:  `path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),` so I created a users/registration/password_change_done.html.